# AngularJS CORS issues data won't load

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am getting the following error message on my angular/asp.net web api project.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:7291/api/products. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7305' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I know it has something to do with CORS not being implemented correctly, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm following a tutorial and as far as I can tell I've got everything right?

Here's the info from the network tab in chrome debug.
Remote Address:[::1]:7291
Request URL:http://localhost:7291/api/products
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Response Headers
 (8)
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:7291
Origin:http://localhost:7305
Referer:http://localhost:7305/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36

Here is where I map the API url.

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular
.module("common.services", ["ngResource"])

.constant("appSettings",
{
    serverPath: "http://localhost:7291/"
})
}());
```

And this is how I'm setting up the EnableCOrsAttribute:

```
 [EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:7305", "*", "*")]
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  If more code is needed please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First Step, use a tool like Postman or Fiddler to verify your service endpoint first to ensure functionality.

It looks as if this is not a CORS issue at all, due to the 500 response:

```
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

A CORS issue on a normal success response is usually manifested as a status 0 or -1 in the client, but what you are experiencing is an error on the server side. I have seen this in my own code and suspect that your implementation on the server side is only injecting the CORS headers at the end of processing the request and as the processing abnormally aborted the CORS headers didn't make it in there.

Once you have confirmed functionality do an OPTIONS request on your endpoint to verify CORS:

```
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7291
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Then inspect the headers of the response, if your CORS is enabled correctly on the server you should see Access-Control-Allow headers similar to this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, ETAG
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:7305
```